# Android (and Windows) to-do list with syncing?

Tags: android, productivity, synchronization, todo

I am looking for an Android to-do list that would be compatible with both phones and tablets.

#### Must have features

- Ability to maintain multiple distinct lists (such as one for personal and work items)
- Compatible with Android 4.2 or greater
- Ability to sync lists between multiple devices
- Set due dates and provide reminders

#### Would like to have

- Windows compatible app that can sync
- Ability to sync lists with other users (such as share a to-do list with other family members, or colleagues)
- Sub-lists
- Tags for classification of lists and list items
- Reoccurring tasks

#### Would be cool if it also did

- Integrate with Exchange, Outlook, and/or Google tasks (or calendars)
- Location-based reminders

Comment: I'm not using any such app myself, but shouldn't most of the Cloud based [Todo apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=6#group_23) match the requirements (especially those using Google Tasks)?

Comment: What about OneNote? I'm not sure if it satisfies all your requirements though.

Comment: @ComFreek I've never thought of OneNote as a "to-do" list type app.  Seems to be more of a side feature of a note taking app.  It would hit some of the important features, but wouldn't be exactly right.  Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: If you can use web-based you could try trello or workflowy or wunderlist. I don't think they have all the "likes"

Comment: I won't post an answer, because I use DropBox to synch (you get 2gB free, which ought to be enough for most ToDo lists :-)   I use the excellent FOSS [tack Coach](http://taskcoach.org/) - check it out; you won't regret it. With DropBox synching my data file, I can happily use both the Windows and the  Android version (in fact, Task Coach is available for Windows, Mac OS X, Linux, BSD, iPhone, iPad, and iPod Touch). great features, great price - give it a try - what do you have to lose?

Answer (score 10):

I recommend [Todoist](https://todoist.com) for you. Let us see how it satisfies your requirements.

**Must Have Features:**

**Ability to maintain multiple distinct lists (such as one for personal and work items)**

In Todoist, you can create multiple lists, how many ever you wish, and also nested lists (lists within lists) up to 4 levels. For instance, during my semester, I have almost a dozen lists for all the types of tasks I need to do.

**Compatible with Android 4.2 or greater**

Yes, Todoist is compatible with Android 4.2 or more.

**Ability to sync lists between multiple devices**

Yes again, Todoist can sync your lists between any number of devices you have.

**Set due dates and provide reminders**

You can set due dates. However, for reminders, you need to subscribe to the premium version which is $29 per year. In my opinion, it is well worth it as there are other features too (I'll describe them at the end).

**Would like to have:**

**Windows-compatible app that can sync**

Bingo! Todoist has an app compatible with Windows 7, 8, 8.1, 10 (Windows 10 even has a UWP app along with the desktop app). The UI will be pretty familiar whichever device you use.

**Ability to sync lists with other users (such as share a to-do list with other family members, or colleagues)**

Sharing is available in Todoist. Once you invite X to a list and (s)he accepts, the list will be added to his/her list too. Plus you can also assign each task to a specific member. However, you can't assign a task to multiple people as Todoist believes it conflicts with the principles of GTD. You can also comment on these tasks and have a discussion with the people shared.

**Sub-lists**

Yes, as mentioned previously, you can create sub-lists up to *4 levels*.

**Tags for classification of lists and list items**

Tags can be assigned but it is a premium feature. So, you will need the subscription.

**Re-occurring tasks**

This can be done too.

**Would be cool if it also did:**

**Integrate with Exchange, Outlook, and/or Google tasks (or calendars)**

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by this, but to be clear -- there is an extension for the Outlook desktop app. It adds itself as a sidebar in Outlook, and you can expand it to see your tasks. <s>There is no calendar integration per se but let me give you another software recommendation for this. Try the app [Sunrise](http://sunrise.am). It integrates with Google calendar, Exchange, and also Todoist (shows your Todoist tasks on the calendar - very neat).</s> Sunrise is dead now. However, Todoist does have calendar integration in its premium subscription.

**Location-based reminders**

Unfortunately, this feature isn't there in Todoist.

**BONUS:**

I just thought I'd give a brief feature overview of Todoist to aid you in making your decision.

- The standout feature of Todoist is what they call *[karma](http://todoist.com/Help/Karma)*. It is basically how they have gamified a tasklist to motivate you to complete your tasks. You gain karma by adding and completing tasks and lose it if you don't complete tasks on time. There are also various levels of karma.
- Another nice feature in my view is you can set due dates by writing them in a human-readable fashion. You can write *today* or *tomorrow* or *next Monday at 2 pm* and Todoist will convert it to a date.
- You can set priorities for tasks. There are 4 levels of priorities which are color-coded too.
- Push notifications. Important events are notified via email or push notifications within the app.
- *The premium subscription:* A premium subscription to Todoist enables you to set reminders to tasks, assign labels and custom filters and add details to tasks using task notes. These are not limited to text files, and you can even attach photos, PDFs, audio notes or even spreadsheets. You can also export your tasks as an ICS file (this syncs!).
- Lastly, Todoist is available on a wide variety of platforms should you want to use it on another platform. This includes the Web, Android (phone and tablet), Android Wear, iPhone and iPad, Apple Watch, Windows, Mac OS, Chrome extension, Firefox add-on, Safari extension, Outlook add-in, <s>Thunderbird extension</s>, and Gmail extension <s>and a Postbox add-in</s> (Postbox and Thunderbird have been deprecated). <s>The only major platform missing, in my opinion, is Windows Phone.</s> RIP Windows Phone

**Other relevant links:**

- [Overview of all features](https://todoist.com/overview)
- [Help section](https://todoist.com/Help)
- [Support forums](https://todoist.com/Support)
- [Todoist Premium](https://todoist.com/premium). Keep in mind that the app itself is free.
- [Todoist GTD (Getting Things Done) Workflow](https://todoist.com/gtd)

Anything I may have missed out on should be covered in these links. You can contact me for any additional queries. And I am not connected to Todoist in any way.

Comment: That's a very well made answer!  However, it reads like an evangelist wrote it.  Were/are you related to the company or the product?

Comment: Haha I have no relation to Todoist. Back then, I was a huge fan of them. I have since moved on to ClickUp recently lol.

Answer (score 3):

What about google [keep](https://keep.google.com/)? It works under Android, Windows/Linux (via browser),
It does not synchronize with Exchange, Outlook but it is simple and cool.

Comment: Does it satisfy the requirement "Set due dates and provide reminders" ?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Yes, well sorta. It now allows reminders and if you use due dates and reminders identically, yes.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [Remember the Milk](http://www.rememberthemilk.com). It has all of your must have features, several desktop apps, ability to share tasks, tags and recurring tasks, integrations with outlook, gmail/google calendar add-ins. It also has a powerful saved search system.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody talked about [Trello](https://trello.com/) yet ?
It's free, there is an app for android (maybe iOS too, but I don't use that) and a website accessible from any browser. You can sync everything.

You can also :

- Do checklists.
- Label (tag) things (what I do is I label things with "Easy", "Average", "hard").
- Create due dates.
- Switch to calendar view.
- Archive things.
- Share the to-do list.

It's quite pretty too !

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend [**Tasks**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.teamtasks.tasks.paid&hl=en) on Android.

## Features

1. Create many lists
2. Compatible since Android 2.2 but with a slick Holo (4.X) interface
3. Syncs directly through Google Tasks

   - so it's available on other Android devices
   - Gmail, Google Calendar or directly via https://mail.google.com/tasks/ig?pli=1
   - and with anything else on any platform that uses the GTasks API
4. Set due dates and provide reminders

   - *Important note:* reminders/due-time are not synced, they're saved per device as the Gtasks API doesn't support that **:(**
5. Sub tasking ad nausium
6. Switch between tree view / due date
7. Homescreen widget
8. Paid app but there's a free version which shows ads

[image: Tasks Android]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [MyLifeOrganized](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mylifeorganized.mlo). It has all the features you mentioned, with the possible exception of the ability to sync lists with other users.

Answer (score 0):

I have switched to Wunderlist from Google Keep, as it is much more convenient
[wunderlist.com/webapp#](https://wunderlist.com/webapp#)

**Partially**: Ability to maintain multiple distinct lists (such as one for personal and work items)*I just created two separate lists for work and general*

**Yes**: Compatible with Android 4.2 or greater

**Yes**: Ability to sync lists between multiple devices

**Yes**: Set due dates and provide reminders

**You can use web version**: Windows compatible app that can sync

**Yes**: Ability to sync lists with other users (such as share a to-do list with other family members, or colleagues)
*I am sharing tasks with my wife, what to buy, etc.*

**Yes**: Sub-lists

**Yes**: Tags for classification of lists and list items

**Yes**: Reoccurring tasks

**Yes**, I am using integration with Outlook calendar on my mobile: Integrate with Exchange, Outlook, and/or Google tasks (or calendars)

**Not sure**: Location-based reminders

**Other benefits:**

- attach files, comments, links
- web, mobile versions
- faster than keep (as for me)
- the interface is straightforward and simpler for me than google keep