# To Do list for both Android and Windows with no user registration required

Tags: windows, android, task-management

I am looking for a To Do list for both Android and Windows (I wouldn't object to Linux, but don't require it) with no user account required (I will synch the data files myself).

- categories, including nesting of categories
- task due dates, with alarms
- task % complete
- task priority
- task description

any other features welcome (such as one task being a prerequisite of the next)

[This question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9819/android-and-windows-to-do-list-with-syncing) comes close, but is not gratis and requires user registration (I do not want my data sitting, possibly unencrypted, on someone's server).

On reflection, I don't require a gratis solution and would be willing to pay up to $20, so long as the data can be synched by DropBox and are encrypted.

---

[Update] To Do List on Android does not remember the database from session to session, so I am looking for an alternative.

I still prefer to synch with DropBox and not have my data on someone else's server, but I could live with that if the data is encrypted on my device & the servers' owners cannot access it

Answer (score 1):

For many years I have used the excellent [TaskCoach](http://www.taskcoach.org/), and only posted this question when I had trouble opening my database on a new Android phone.

I post this answer to help anyone with similar requirements (but I continue to welcome alternatives).

---

> **What is Task Coach?**
>
> Task Coach is a simple open source todo manager to keep track of
>   personal tasks and todo lists. It is designed for composite tasks, and
>   also offers effort tracking, categories, notes and more.
>
> **What platforms are supported?**
>
> Task Coach is available for Windows, Mac OS X, Linux, BSD, iPhone,
>   iPad, and iPod Touch.
>
> **What does it cost?**
>
> The desktop versions of Task Coach are completely
>   free. The iOS versions of Task Coach come with a small price tag
>   because it costs us money to make them available.

---

> **Task Coach for the desktop**
>
> The desktop version of Task Coach (Windows, Mac, Linux, BSD) has the
>   following features: 
>   •Creating, editing, and deleting tasks and
>   subtasks.
>   •Tasks have a subject, description, priority, start date,
>   due date, a completion date and an optional reminder. Tasks can recur
>   on a daily, weekly or monthly basis.
>   •Tasks can be viewed as a list or
>   as a tree.
>   •Tasks can be sorted by all task attributes, e.g. subject,
>   budget, budget left, due date, etc.
>   •Several filters to e.g. hide
>   completed tasks or view only tasks that are due today.
>   •Tasks can be
>   created by dragging an e-mail message from a mail user agent (Outlook,
>   Thunderbird, Claws Mail, Apple Mail) onto a task viewer.
>   •Attachments
>   can be added to tasks, notes, and categories by dragging and dropping
>   files, e-mail messages, or URL's onto a task, note or category.
>   •Task
>   status depends on its subtask and vice versa. E.g. if you mark the
>   last uncompleted subtask as completed, the parent task is
>   automatically marked as completed too.
>   •Tasks and notes can be
>   assigned to user-defined categories.
>   •Settings are persistent and
>   saved automatically. The last opened file is loaded automatically when
>   starting Task Coach.
>   •Tracking time spent on tasks. Tasks can have a
>   budget. Time spent can be viewed by individual effort period, by day,
>   by week, and by month.
>   •The Task Coach file format (.tsk) is XML.
>   •Tasks, notes, effort, and categories can be exported to HTML and CSV
>   (comma separated format). Effort can be exported to iCalendar/ICS
>   format as well.
>   •Tasks, effort, notes, and categories can be printed.
>   When printing, Task Coach prints the information that is visible in
>   the current view, including any filters and sort order.
>    •Task Coach
>   can be run from a removable medium.
>   •Tasks and notes can be
>   synchronized via a Funambol server such as My Funambol.
>
> **Task Coach for iOS**
>
> There is a todo-list application for iPhone, iPad and iPod Touch that
>   can synchronize with Task Coach through the network. Main features
>   are:
>
> •Hierarchical categories.
>   •Editing of task subject, description,
>   dates and completed status.
>   •Tap on the task's led icon to mark it
>   complete.
>    •Available in English and French.
>
> **Task Coach for Android**
>
> The Android version is separately developed; we don't support it
>   ourselves. See [the developer's site](https://sites.google.com/site/ajiget/programs/android-programs/taskcoach-for-android) for details.

Google play for the Android version is [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hgTaskCoach&hl=en_GB)

Obligatory graphic:

[image: Task Coach screenshot]